# How to align img + text to center of grid React

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get the image + text in the grid from this picture to be centered, how do i do that?[image: Gridbox]

Comment: This question seems to be more about css than react. Consider posting some of your markup /styles and what you've tried before. If react isn't specifically relevant, remove that tag. Otherwise please add some explanation as to why this is a react-focused question.

Comment: please try adding the CSS, HTML. It will be better for us to understand what's going on in the html structure

Comment: you should look at using css grid or flexbox.

Comment: There are multiple ways to center align your contents, it depends on your code. So please post your jsx/html and CSS used if any

Answer (score 0):

please check the following code in this link https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-phoebe-7lso94?file=/src/App.js:24-561

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="border border-black mx-auto w-[500px] h-[500px] grid justify-center items-center">
        <div className="text-center">
          <img
            src="https://w7.pngwing.com/pngs/293/485/png-transparent-tailwind-css-hd-logo.png"
            alt=""
            className="w-[100px] mx-auto"
          />
          <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
          <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have shown you the easiest way to align an element both vertically and horizontally.
let me know if this solves your problem!

```css
img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

div.text-center {
  width: 420px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #dfdfdf;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-center">
  <img src="https://w7.pngwing.com/pngs/293/485/png-transparent-tailwind-css-hd-logo.png"/>
  <div>
    <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
    <p>Start editing to see some magic happen!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```